# C Using a n+1 dimentional array as a n dimention array parameter

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

My question is, when you have an array `tab[a][b][c]`, are you allowed to use `tab[a]` as a parameter `array[b][c]`?

Here is an example:

```
void function(int tab[5][6])
{
    tab[4][3]++;
}

int main()
{
    int tab[9][5][6];
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        function(tab[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MSVC "lets me" but I don't know if it is strictly legal. NB your usage has *undefined behaviour* because of the operation `tab[4][3]++;` on uninitialised data.

Comment: Since the expression `tab[i]` doesn't apply the `&`, `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operators to the array, the expression is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. Since `int tab[5][6]` in the prototype of `function` is adjusted to type `int (*)[6]`, the types of the argument and parameter match. The *only* problem is the read of an uninitialized value @WeatherVane mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when you have an array `tab[a][b][c]`, are you allowed to use `tab[a]` as a parameter `array[b][c]`?

Yes

---

`int tab[9][5][6];` is type [array 9 of array 5 of array 6 of int](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+tab%5B9%5D%5B5%5D%5B6%5D%3B).

`tab[i]` is type *array 5 of array 6 of `int`*.`

When code calls `function(tab[i])`, `tab[i]` is converted to the address of the first element.  In this case, that is `&tab[i][0]`, this is of type [pointer to array 6 of int](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*tab%29%5B6%5D).

`void function(int tab[5][6])` operates the same as `void function(int (*tab)[6])`.  IOWs, the function expects a [pointer to array 6 of int](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*tab%29%5B6%5D).  The `5` is advisory to coders, but not functionality useful to code.

Good: the function call provides the expected type.

`tab[4][3]++;` operates on the `tab[4][3]`.  The `4` in says to use the 4th indexed element (starting from 0) of `int (*tab)[6]`.  Fortunately this is OK as the calling code's array is large enough to handle index 4.